# Error upon converting a pandas dataframe to spark DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I created a pandas dataframe out of some StackOverFlow posts. Used lxml.eTree to separate the code_blocks and the text_blocks. Below code shows the basic outline :

```
import lxml.etree

a1 = tokensentRDD.map(lambda (a,b): (a,''.join(map(str,b))))
a2 = a1.map(lambda (a,b): (a, b.replace("&lt;", "<")))
a3 = a2.map(lambda (a,b): (a, b.replace("&gt;", ">")))

def parsefunc (x):
    html = lxml.etree.HTML(x)
    code_block = html.xpath('//code/text()')
    text_block = html.xpath('// /text()') 

    a4 =  code_block
    a5 =  len(code_block)
    a6 =  text_block
    a7 =  len(text_block)
    a8 = ''.join(map(str,text_block)).split(' ')
    a9 =  len(a8)
    a10 = nltk.word_tokenize(''.join(map(str,text_block)))

    numOfI = 0
    numOfQue = 0
    numOfExclam = 0

    for x in a10:
        if x == 'I':
            numOfI +=1
        elif x == '?':
            numOfQue +=1
        elif x == '!':
            numOfExclam
    return (a4,a5,a6,a7,a9,numOfI,numOfQue, numOfExclam)

a11 = a3.take(6)
a12 = map(lambda (a,b): (a, parsefunc(b)), a11)

columns = ['code_block', 'len_code', 'text_block', 'len_text', 'words@text_block', 'numOfI', 'numOfQ', 'numOfExclam']
index = map(lambda x:x[0], a12)
data = map(lambda x:x[1], a12)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = columns, index = index)
df.index.name = 'Id'
df

    code_block  len_code    text_block  len_text    words@text_block    numOfI  numOfQ  numOfExclam
Id                              
4   [decimal    3   [I want to use a track-bar to change a form's ...   18  72  5   1   0
6   [div, ]     5   [I have an absolutely positioned , div, conta...    22  96  4   4   0
9   [DateTime]  1   [Given a , DateTime, representing a person's ...    4   21  2   2   0
11  [DateTime]  1   [Given a specific , DateTime, value, how do I...    12  24  2   1   0
```

I need to create a Spark DataFrame on order to apply machine learning algorithms on the output. I tried:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(df).show()
```

The error I receive is:

```
TypeError: not supported type: <class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'>
```

Can someone tell me a proper way to convert a Pandas DataFrame into A Spark DataFrame?

Comment: You've omitted the most important part of the code (`return (list of variables)`).

Comment: I'm sorry where should I include it?

Comment: Just [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35182717/edit) so it is clear what is returned from the function. Example input would be useful as well.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the incomplete details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not related to Pandas. Both `code_block` (`a4`) and `text_block` (`a6`) contain `lxml` specific objects which cannot be encoded using SparkSQL types. Converting these to strings should be just enough.

```
a4 = [str(x) for x in code_block]
a6 = [str(x) for x in text_block]
```

Comment: It worked, but doesn't display the Index column (the one with 'Id' values). Can you please tell me how do I specify Index to a Spark DataFrame?

Comment: It is not possible. Spark DataFrames don't support indexes. If you want it included you should convert it to normal column.